# Include CSS-File in *.tpl

Tags: css, include, smarty

I'm trying to program a template with smarty, so i started to build a layout in HTML and, as expected, with CSS in an extra .css-file. When i had finished it, i started to adapt it to smarty, but i had realized, that Smarty does not work with "normal" css. Damn delimiters ^_^
Though, i tried to include the .css-file with:

```
{include file="templates_css.css"}
```

and changed my css-code a bit:

```
<style type="text/css">
.body {ldelim}
width: 990px;
margin: 0 auto;
{rdelim}

.title {ldelim}
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 275%;
margin-left: 230px;
padding: 40px;
color: #929292
{rdelim}
</style>
```

This is what i read the last hour about "including css-files in smarty, and they recommended "Thanks! It

Comment: You don't want to use Smarty inside your CSS file. Leave it as pure CSS. What are you actually trying to do with your CSS?

Comment: Why do you want your styles to be included via the style tag?

Comment: Uhm,... When i include my styles in pure html, so i realize it via <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH_TO_CSS.css" />
but smarty ignores my styles when try it this way.
So i have to find another way to include my styles for the layout of my template

Comment: It's really better to fix the original problem since embedding styles this way reduces the ability to cache comment content... are you certain the path to the file is correct?

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry for wasting your Time. I think i did not understand smarty enough :s
I have another idea to complete my 'mission' ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret on using smarty is not how to use the delimiters. The secret hides in the way smarty handles the path. For example:

- `...\htdocs\smarty` <- smarty library
- `...\htdocs\myWebsite\css\your.css` <- your stylesheet
- `...\htdocs\myWebsite\templates\base.tpl` <- the file where you load your .css
- `...\htdocs\myWebsite\index.php` <- the file where you load the template (base.tpl)

So... If you see your template is in `\templates\base.tpl` and your css in `\css\your.css`, you may think that you need the relative path from your template to your stylesheet. That is wrong! Note, that the, let's call it "position", of your template file will be the same as the file which is loading the template file(here it is the index.php). That means your css include, like you do it in HTML will not have the path from your template to your css, but from your index.php to your css.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have stylesheets  seperated from `.tpl` files.

It is simple to use `html` tags with `smarty`.

And so you can simply call css from `.tpl` file as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$RootDirectory}/path_to_css_directory/templates_css.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**

You Can call external style sheet like add following line in your tpl file
 
OR
If you want to use internal style then just write 
{literal}
here start style tag 
add inline style here
Here End style Tag
{/literal}

Thanks